# Bootstrap 4 align divs left and right, for small screen show them in separate rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Below is the code I tried:
I want an image on left and buttons on right. For small screens the buttons should move below the image in a new row.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-lg-between">
      <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" class="coverImage">
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Follow</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Add to Favourite</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But on small screen the right part (the buttons) are just gettings stacked inline with the image on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each part `<div class="col-md-6">` (image and buttons)
`col-md-6` what means that in `sm` screen it be `12`

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uhgztkqb/2/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" class="coverImage">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Follow</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Add to Favourite</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Edit to align right the buttons use:**
 `text-md-right` to second `div class="col-md-6"`

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-md-right">
```

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/uhgztkqb/8/
Learn here:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/

Comment: But here the buttons are not positioned to the extreme right , they begin just after the width of first div.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `col-6`
- Use `text-right` to align buttons on the right side

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" class="coverImage">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
      <button class="btn btn-success">Follow</button>
      <button class="btn btn-success">Add to Favourite</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to align the button on the left side for **`md`** screens, use **`text-md-left`** also.

Answer (score 0):

Use class **d-flex** , use **flex-md-column** for display vertically  image and below buttons for medium and large screen devices , and  use **flex-md-row** for display horizontally image and right side buttons in small screens.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex flex-md-column flex-sm-row justify-content-between">
      
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" class="coverImage">
   
        <div class="button-div">
          <button class="btn btn-success">Follow</button>
          <button class="btn btn-success">Add to Favourite</button>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```